# How to set background color in AppGyver Supersonic?

Tags: javascript, css, steroids

I am unable to find any documentation about how to change the "real" background color in an AppGyver Supersonic app. I can set the color of `body` element with CSS but user can still see the default white in the bounce effect when dragging the screen up or down (in iOS). Same is for the list component background color, is there some way to change it? Setting `background-color` for the list `div` element does nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AppGyver dev here! On iOS, it's available via the legacy Steroids API: `steroids.view.setBackgroundColor("FF0000")` (and `steroids.view.setBackgroundImage`). Supersonic API implementation is pending Android support for this.

API reference:
http://docs.appgyver.com/en/stable/steroids_Steroids%20Views_steroids.view_view.setBackgroundColor.md.html#steroids.view.setBackgroundColor
http://docs.appgyver.com/en/stable/steroids_Steroids%20Views_steroids.view_view.setBackgroundImage.md.html#steroids.view.setBackgroundImage